# catalyst DBIx::Class::TimeStamp set time on insertion to database not working

Tags: mysql, macos, perl, datetime, dbix-class

I am using Catalyst and [DBIx::Class::TimeStamp](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx::Class::TimeStamp?) and I have one of my ResultSet classes configured to set a DateTime column to the current time whenever a row is inserted:

```
__PACKAGE__->load_components("TimeStamp");

__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
   start_time => { data_type => 'datetime', set_on_create => 1 }
);
```

A time is inserted whenever a row is created, however it's about 6 hours in the future. Whenever I insert a time using MySQL and its NOW() function, it gets the time right. Does anyone know why this is occurring? I'm developing on a mac, if that helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`DBIx::Class::TimeStamp` uses `DateTime->now` for getting time, so result depends on your computer settings. But MySQL’s `NOW()` result depends on MySQL settings. See time zone settings on your computer, your database server, and MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just override the `get_timestamp` column in the Result class and return a DateTime object with the correct timezone set.  For example:

```
package My::Schema::Result::MyTable;

# ... snip ...

sub get_timestamp {
    return DateTime->now( time_zone => "GMT" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To the start time hash, add:

timezone => 'local'